# Connect to a remote Linux server that is in default setup, not configured to be connected?

Tags: ssh, remote, vnc, sshd

In our Company we have an internal-wikipedia-like help site. The Problem is, the MindTouch-Wiki is out of date, so I have to update it!

The Problem is, it's running virtual. It's Ubuntu 7.7

In Microsoft Server 2003/2008, I can't connect to the machine using "Connect to virtual machine"

I'm not familiar with Linux, is there a way to connect to the Ubuntu that is open by default?

Like RDP over VNC in Windows?

Comment: Please type the title of your question in Google before asking here, there's tons and tons of information about this available already.

Comment: `ssh` for non-root users works by default I think. If you find any other such a way to connect that is open by default, let us know, so we can report it as a bug.

Comment: @Mat No offense, but isn't Unix&Linux a good place to list the different ways to remotely connect to a Linux?

Comment: @Emmanuel: repeating information that's already widely available all over the place just adds noise. If the question was more specific in any way, including perhaps something the OP tried but didn't work or wasn't satisfactory, could be interesting. As it is, it's a question that search engines already address. (Also note the tooltip on the downvote button.)

Comment: @Mat I think there is some value in repeating that information here. It's because the StackExchange system works very good in terms of keeping the *important* information - which may technically be trivial *(!)*, and seems to be able to create a very high quality over time for the *important* information - which is refined often, and has competition in cuality by duplicates. So we can hope that the this "some value" will become a "substantial value" over time.

Answer (score 0):

If `ssh` is installed, it works by default for non-root users I think.

If you find any other such a way to connect that is open by default, let us know,
so we can report it as a bug. :)

For 'ssh' to work, you need the package `openssh-server`.
The remaining question is whether that is installed by default.

I did not check, but I woud expect that it is not installed on a desktop install of Ubuntu, but it will be for sure on a server install.

The `ssh` server can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

There may be no `ssh` client available on Windows by default, as @mintyfreshpenguin pointed out. 
It's the program you need to make the connection. There is a very good `ssh` client that runs on Windows, named [`putty`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

It's free (as in "freedom", and as in "free beer" too) and easy to handle:

You only need to download one exe file, and run it, without installing anything.
(It will look complicated if it's new to you. You know where to ask if the manual and google did not help.)

There is also a installer package with some related tools that you may need later (except puttytel).
Install that if you can, or choose the separate `putty.exe`:

On http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html
In the section "Binaries", either choose the "Installer" with a version number in the name, like
`putty-0.63-installer.exe` at the time of writing, or the `PuTTY:` at the top of the list,
`putty.exe`.

Comment: Don't forget you will also need an ssh client to connect to the server, once installed.

Comment: So, do you mean Windows does not have a ssh client installed by default? That's irritating. You must be joking ;) But he can install putty, it does `ssh` plus a whole lot more he may need.

Comment: As far as I remember windows doesn’t have an ssh client out of the box. Ubuntu does. It's been years since I've used Win now. Thought it worth a mention.

Comment: Of course you are right - that's why I tried to sneak in a clear hint to use `putty` in the last comment. Will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather use a GUi then you can install VNC in the same manner as ssh see Volker's answer for command. Tightvnc Server is a nice light choice. Of cause this assumes your virtual Ubuntu has a DE installed.
If you want to see what packages are available use `apt-cache search string`

Comment: But these are not running by default, right? That seems to be the OP's problem: He needs to connect before he can install something. But the idea is useful anyway, because it could be done if the my answer worked to get `ssh` access, that could be used to get a gui connection service installed and running. Could make it much nicer for him.

Comment: I don't think anything is available by default not even Telnet. As you pointed out this type of behaviour would be considered a bug by most if not all *nix users. Perhaps the OP could tell us what exactly he/she can do. I assume they have some kind of access to a CLI/GUI locally.